# References for groups as symmetry elements acting on some structure

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-actions, symmetry, online-resources

The definition that I knew about groups were the abstract definition, that any set $G$ together with an operation $*$ is a group $(G,*)$ iff $G$ is closed under group operation, associative,  and has inverse and identity element. But recently I watched [Richard E Borchereds lectures on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8yHsr3EFj51pjBvvCPipgAT3SYpIiIsJ), which give a more concrete picture of groups by introducing groups as some symmetry elements acting on a set or some structures and introduced concepts like Cayley graphs. By these pictures we can associate a structure for any abstract group, that acts on it, which I came to know as Cayley theorem. These pictures are new to me.

Can anyone point me to some materials where I can read about these in details?

Comment: A search for _group actions_ finds many links some of which may help you.